# Aura components going to retire?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am new to salesforce and currently working on LWC related project. I got a requirement to use aura inside LWC but I heared that salesforce is going to withdraw aura component stuffs. Is it true?

Answer (score 4):

It is not correct that Salesforce will withdraw Aura Component stuff (Its not documented anywhere so unless you see in any official docs its not true). Salesforce supports both the programming model (Aura and LWC) and you can always use LWC inside aura components while other way round is not possible.

Salesforce has excellent [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_lwc_or_aura) on when to choose Aura vs LWC. Below is what is officially recommended

> Always choose Lightning Web Components unless you need a feature that isn’t supported.

***If you need to use an unsupported experience or feature or use an unsupported interface, do most of the development in Lightning Web Components. Wrap your finished component in an Aura component that simply accesseses the experience, feature, or interface.***

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am having one angular application which I can embed into an aura component using lightning:container and I tried to embed that aura into LWC. But since you are saying we cant use aura inside LWC is there a way I can embed the same angular application in LWC <br/> <br/>  `<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
 <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.speech + '/index.html'}"/>
</aura:component>`

Comment: It's not a good idea to use lwc and angular all at once. I suggest use lightning:container that should be fine.

Comment: Any issues will come like XSS, if I go for iframe approach?

Comment: No it will not provided you use HTTPS url and also adhere to security guidelines like not passing sessionID etc and server all the Javascript files from salesforce static resources. Also lightning:container component has security guidelines documented. Please use that

Comment: Any idea of how to use  lightning:container in LWC. I tried using like this   <lightning-container src={rangeSliderURL}></lightning-container> but getting error as "No MODULE named markup://lightning:container found" . So i tried using <lightning:container src={rangeSliderURL}></lightning:container> and i am not seeing the output in UI. Any help on this would be appreciated.